# Why an entry of pure virtual function in virtual table is required

Tags: c++

My understanding regarding virtual table is , whenever compiler find virtual function in a class it creates a virtual table for the class and all the function pointer for virtual function will be placed in that table.

But when it comes to pure virtual function we are not going to call that function in any point of time. So why that entry of pure virtual function is required in the virtual table.

```
virtual void myFunction() = 0 ;
```

Comment: That question makes no sense. A class with pure virtual functions cannot be instantiated. Hence virtual function table for this class does not exist.

Comment: @void_ptr virtual function table is binded with class not object. as soon as you create a class, compiler will create a vtable even if you don't have any object of that class.

Answer (score 9):

The declaration is required because you need to tell the compiler to reserve a slot in the vtable for that specific method starting from the base class in which it is declared (which is the type you could want to use when calling a method on a derived class)

Just to give you the idea let's make an example (which is not to be considered exactly what happens under the hood). Let's suppose you have three virtual methods in `Base`, one of which is pure,

```
class Base {
  virtual void pure() = 0;
  virtual void nonpure() { }
  virtual void nonpure2() { }
};
```

so the `Base` vtable will look like

```
0 [ pure ] -> nothing
1 [ nonpure ] -> address of Base::nonpure
2 [ nonpure2] -> address of Base::nonpure2
```

now let's derive it with

```
class Derive : public Base {
  virtual pure() override { }
  virtual nonpure2() override { }
};
```

`Derived` vtable will look like

```
0 [ pure ] -> address of Derived::pure
1 [ nonpure ] -> address of Base::nonpure
2 [ nonpure2 ] -> address of Derived::nonpure2
```

When you then try to do

```
Base* derived = new Derived();
derived->pure();
```

The method is roughly compiled as

```
address = derived->vtable[0];
call address
```

If you don't declare the pure virtual method in the `Base` class there is no way to know its index in the vtable (0) in this case at compile time since the method is not present at all.

But, if the vtable has 'a hole' in it (an implementation is missing), you can't instantiate that specific class type.

Comment: I think that this is what the OP is after, yes:)

Answer (score 6):

You cannot instantiate an object of an abstract class. Which actually makes your question kinda meaningless: since you will never instantiate your abstract class, the virtual table for that class is not needed at all. (In reality it might be needed temporarily during construction/destruction, but this is a different story.)

When you actually instantiate an object, it is an object of some *derived* class, which is no longer abstract. It does not have any pure virtual functions anymore. The derived class that you actually instantiate has all pure virtual functions overridden by that time. This is why an entry is needed in the virtual method table - to store a pointer to the actual overrider function.

Later in your code, you might call `myFunction()` through a pointer to that abstract base class

```
MyAbstractBaseClass *ptr = some_function();
// Pointer actually points to some non-abstract derived object
ptr->myFunction();
```

The compiler will generate code that will go into the virtual method table associated with `*ptr` object, extract the pointer entry that corresponds to `myFunction()` and pass the control trough that pointer. As I said above, that pointer will actually point to an overriding function from some derived class. This is exactly what that entry was reserved for.